# String replace regex character classes using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This string has regex character classes which need to be removed. As well as reduce multiple spaces to single space.
I can chain `replace()` but thought to ask if one can suggest a one regex code to do the whole job at one go. How can it be done? Thanks

> "\n\t\t\t   \n\n\t           \n\t           \t\tFood      and drinks \n   \t\n"

This is needed:

> "Food and drinks"

```
var newStr = oldStr.replace(/[\t\n ]+/g, '');  //<-- failed to do the job
```

Comment: Don't forget that replacing the spaces will replace _all_ the spaces.

Comment: I wouldn't do it in one replace, although I think it is possible. Its much more clear to use one regex for removing chars, one for retaining single spaces, and one for trimming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to remove all leading and trailing whitespace (space, tab, newline) but leave the spaces in the internal string. You can use the whitespace character class `\s` as shorthand, and match *either* the start or the end of the string.

```
var oldStr = "\n\t\t\t \n\n\t \n\t \t\tFood and drinks \n \t\n";

// ^\s+ => match one or more whitespace characters at the start of the string
// \s+$ => match one or more whitespace characters at the end of the string
// | => match either of these subpatterns
// /g => global i.e every match (at the start *and* at the end)

var newStr = oldStr.replace(/^\s+|\s$/g/, '');
```

If you also want to reduce the internal spaces to a single space, I *would* recommend using two regexes and chaining them:

```
var oldStr = "\n\t\t\t \n\n\t \n\t \t\tFood   and      drinks \n \t\n";
var newStr = oldStr.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

After the first `.replace()` all of the leading and trailing whitespace is removed, leaving only the internal spaces. Replace runs of one or more space/tab/newline with a single space.

One other way to go could be to reduce all runs of whitespace to a single space, then trim the one remaining leading and trailing space:

```
var oldStr = "\n\t\t\t \n\n\t \n\t \t\tFood   and      drinks \n \t\n";

var newStr = oldStr.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim();
// or reversed
var newStr = oldStr.trim().replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
```

`.trim()` doesn't exist prior to ES5.1 (ECMA-262) but the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim#Polyfill) is essentially `.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '')` (with a couple of other characters added) anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend this pattern (assuming you want to keep `\n`s or `\t`s in your main string):

```
/^[\t\n ]+|[\t\n ]+$/g
```

If you don't want to keep them, you can use something like this:

```
/^[\t\n ]+|[\t\n]*|[\t\n ]+$/g
```

Comment: I tried the last pattern since I don't want to keep them, but it leaves a new line at the end. Try it in the console and you should see.

Comment: Trying your first removed the leading but left the trailing spaces, because it needs the global option to get both: `oldStr.replace(/^[\t\n ]+|[\t\n ]+$/g, '');`